# Separating content within div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="somecontent_1">...</div>
  <div class="somecontent_2">...</div>
  <div class="somecontent_3">...</div>
  <div class="somecontent_4">...</div>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to separate the content with a separate page so it looks something like this:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="somecontent">...</div>
  <div class="somecontent">...</div>
</div>
<div class="newpage">
  <div class="somecontent">...</div>
  <div class="somecontent">...</div>
</div>
```

The function checks the height of each class `somecontent` and if it's larger than a certain amount, I need to move the content to a new page.
My guess is that I would need to create an empty div (newpage) and then fetch the elements after the height is exceeded and move them to the empty newpage and continue iterate like that.

My question would be how I would get all content that are after the last element that reached the height so I can move it to the new empty page that I would create. Other solutions are most welcome if there is a better way of doing it!

The code I came up with looks like this:

```
    var page = $('.page');
    var pageHeight = 0;
    $.each(page.find('.somecontent'), function() {
      if (pageHeight > 1000) {
        page.next('<div class="newpage"></div>');
        /* Somehow get all elements to add to the newly created page */
        page.next('.newpage').append(<NEXT_ELEMENTS>);
        pageHeight = 0;
      }
      pageHeight = pageHeight + $(this).height();
    });
```

Comment: What does *wrap the content below it as a new page* mean? "Page" as in HTML document?

Comment: Sorry, the page I'm referring to is a made up A4 page for the user, not HTML document :)  For example like a google doc A4 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach the `page` which answers the height criterion use the `.nextAll` function to get all the next siblings of it, then use `.wrapAll` to wrap them with your `newpage div`.

Here is the corresponding documentation of [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/) and [wrapAll](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), it has everything you need to cover your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

See comments in line below.

```js
// Instead of the $.each() utiility function
// Just loop over each content area that needs
// examination
$('.somecontent').each(function(index, item) {
  // Check if the height of the item is greater than the target (20px for this example)
  if (parseInt(getComputedStyle(item).height,10) > 20) {
    // Make a new div after the div that the item is currently in
    // if one doesn't already exist
    if($(".newpage").length === 0){
      $(item.closest(".page")).after('<div class="newpage"></div>');
    }
    // Move the item into the new div
    $(item.closest(".page")).next('.newpage').append(item);
  }
});

//console.log(document.body.innerHTML);  // shows resulting HTML
```

```css
div.page {border:1px solid red; }
div.newpage {border:1px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="somecontent">This<br>is<br>some<br>content</div>
  <div class="somecontent">This is some content</div>
  <div class="somecontent">
    <ul>
      <li>This</li>
      <li>is</li>
      <li>some</li>
      <li>content</li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="somecontent">Other</div>
</div>
```